# Microsoft specific _sntscanf_s function acting strangely

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-2015

I'm not quite sure how the Microsoft specific [_sntscanf_s](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dktz45bk.aspx) function is supposed to work.

On my Visual Studio 2015 (14.0.25431.01 Update 3) the output of the following program compiled with the **v140** toolkit is:

> 23.00000
>   Converted fields 1

Which is wrong IMO, whereas with the **v120** toolkit the output is:

> 0.00000
>   Converted fields 1

Which is correct IMO.

```
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  TCHAR szBuffer[10];

  szBuffer[0] = _T('0');
  szBuffer[1] = _T('\0');
  szBuffer[2] = _T('2');   // replace '2' by '\0' and it works as expected
  szBuffer[3] = _T('3');
  szBuffer[4] = _T('\0');
  szBuffer[5] = _T('\0');

  double d;
  int conv = _sntscanf_s(szBuffer, _countof(szBuffer), _T("%lf"), &d);
  printf("%f\n", d);
  printf("Converted fields %d\n", conv);
  return 0;
}
```

As per the comment in the program, if you replace `szBuffer[2] = '2';` by `szBuffer[2] = '\0';` it works as expected (Output: `0.00000`).

Also if this line:

```
int conv = _sntscanf_s(szBuffer, _countof(szBuffer), _T("%lf"), &d);
```

is replaced by:

```
int conv = _sntscanf_s(szBuffer, _tcslen(szBuffer), _T("%lf"), &d);
```

the output is always `0.00000` regardless of the toolkit.

To me this looks like a bug. As far as I understand, the scan should stop at the first NUL character encountered.

Has anybody else encountered this problem?

Comment: It probably doesn't matter, but the proper way of assigning a character literal value to a `TCHAR` is using `_T('c')` or `_TEXT('c')`. Also, which flavor of `TCHAR` are you using, UNICODE or ANSI?

Comment: @IanAbbott You are right concerning the proper way off assigning a character literal. And yes, actually it doesn't matter here. I'm using the UNICODE flavor but the problem remains the same with the ANSI flavour.

Comment: Looks like https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4a04b861-8b16-4bb3-8a0d-f4e78b1c2a5a/sntscanfs-doesnt-work-as-expected-in-vs2015?forum=vcgeneral  --> "the problem is that it sees the 0 and looks for the 'X' which it doesnt find it then attempts to push back the '\0' which doesnt get push back (...) it then gets the next char which is the char beyond the '\0'"  (a bug)

Comment: @chux That looks suspiciously close to this question. Perhaps Michael is testing us. :)

Comment: @IanAbbott So a dupe, but the dupe is off_site?

Comment: Ok, I more or less got it. Thanks. Maybe the question should be closed then...