# Visual C++ 2017 bug - MFC DDX_Text for double

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I just installed Visual Studio 2017 community edition.  I created a MFC project using the app wizard taking all the defaults.  Then I added two edit boxes on the about dialog.  Then I mapped two variables of type double to these two edit boxes.  Then I added a handler for OK button.  Here is relevant code:

```
class CAboutDlg : public CDialogEx
{
    double m_f;
    afx_msg void OnBnClickedOk();
    double m_f2;
};

void CAboutDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_EDIT1, m_f);
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_EDIT2, m_f2);
}

void CAboutDlg::OnBnClickedOk()
{
    if (!UpdateData(TRUE))
    {
        return;
    }

    CString s;
    s.Format(_T("m_f = %g"), m_f);
    AfxMessageBox(s);
    s.Format(_T("m_f2 = %g"), m_f2);
    AfxMessageBox(s);

    CDialogEx::OnOK();
}
```

What I noticed is that in Release mode, if I entered 0.56 in the first edit box and 0 in the second edit box and click OK button.  The m_f and m_f2 values are displayed as 0.56 and 56 (instead of 0).  Anyone else notice this bug?  I cannot believe existence of such a bug.

I also played around with the project general settings such as Windows SDK version, Platform Toolset, use of MFC (static or shared library) and character set (Unicode or nonUnicode).  The only setting that I get the values displayed correctly is to use Windows SDK version = 10.0.15063.0, Platform toolset=Visual Studio 2017 v141, use MFC static library.

Comment: Maybe you are hit by [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43679807/microsoft-specific-sntscanf-s-function-acting-strangely)

Comment: What does `GetWindowText` give?

Comment: GetWindowText gives correct value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem with MFC related to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43679807/microsoft-specific-sntscanf-s-function-acting-strangely)

In order to circumvent this problem, I reimplemented the `DDX_Text` function calling it `DDX_Text2` and using this function instead of `DDX_Text` for doubles and floats.

The code of `AfxTextFloatFormat` is copied from the MFC sources, the only difference is that `szBuffer` is zero filled before the call to `GetWindowText`.

```
//
// Reimpelementation of AfxTextFloatFormat because of buggy _sntscanf_s function
//
// See:
// - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4a04b861-8b16-4bb3-8a0d-f4e78b1c2a5a/sntscanfs-doesnt-work-as-expected-in-vs2015?forum=vcgeneral
// - https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1773279/bug-in-sntscanf-s
// - https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1642606/mfc-cdialog-dodataexchange-cdataexchange-pdx-fails-when-value-is-zero

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "TextFloatFormatPatch.h"

#ifdef _DEBUG
#undef THIS_FILE
static char THIS_FILE[] = __FILE__;
#endif


// Copied from MFC source code

static void AFXAPI AfxTextFloatFormat(CDataExchange* pDX, int nIDC,
  void* pData, double value, int nSizeGcvt)
{
  ASSERT(pData != NULL);

  pDX->PrepareEditCtrl(nIDC);
  HWND hWndCtrl;
  pDX->m_pDlgWnd->GetDlgItem(nIDC, &hWndCtrl);

  const int TEXT_BUFFER_SIZE = 400;
  TCHAR szBuffer[TEXT_BUFFER_SIZE] = { 0 };          // added: initlialize whole buffer with 0
                                             
  if (pDX->m_bSaveAndValidate)
  {
    ::GetWindowText(hWndCtrl, szBuffer, _countof(szBuffer));

    double d;
    if (_sntscanf_s(szBuffer, _countof(szBuffer), _T("%lf"), &d) != 1)
    {
      AfxMessageBox(AFX_IDP_PARSE_REAL);
      pDX->Fail();            // throws exception
    }
    if (nSizeGcvt == FLT_DIG)
      *((float*)pData) = (float)d;
    else
      *((double*)pData) = d;
  }
  else
  {
    ATL_CRT_ERRORCHECK_SPRINTF(_sntprintf_s(szBuffer, _countof(szBuffer), _countof(szBuffer) - 1, _T("%.*g"), nSizeGcvt, value));
    AfxSetWindowText(hWndCtrl, szBuffer);
  }
}


void AFXAPI DDX_Text2(CDataExchange* pDX, int nIDC, float& value)
{
    AfxTextFloatFormat(pDX, nIDC, &value, value, FLT_DIG); // float
}


void AFXAPI DDX_Text2(CDataExchange* pDX, int nIDC, double& value)
{
    AfxTextFloatFormat(pDX, nIDC, &value, value, DBL_DIG); // double
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Michael for the solution.  Since this is such a fundamental bug, I  hope Microsoft would fix it in the next Visual Studio update.

Comment: @user1998863 I'm not quite sure what configuration is needed so this bug shows up. Referring to the SO article mentioned in the answer: the problem doesn't happen with the old v120 tool set but it happens with the newer v140 toolset and apparently also with the v141 toolset (which comes with Vs2017), at leat on your computer. On the other hand on a coworker's computer the bug shows never up, with any toolset. Anyway, I didn't look into this more because I just needed it to work and my fix made it work again without too much trouble. Upvote would be appreciated.

Comment: I did some further research on this.  It seems that if we copy ucrtbase.dll from C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Redist\ucrt\DLLs to the exe folder, then everything works.  This is based on the conversation here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4a04b861-8b16-4bb3-8a0d-f4e78b1c2a5a/sntscanfs-doesnt-work-as-expected-in-vs2015?forum=vcgeneral.  I guess the vc++ 2017 redistributables and visual studio 2017 install do not deploy the correct ucrtbase.dll to windows system32/sysWOW64 folders.

Comment: This problem existed in VC++ 2015.  I am amazed Microsoft still allows this to exist in VC++ 2017.

Comment: An alternative solution would be to use app-local deployment of the Universal CRT (see [C-Runtime Deployment: Why choose AppLocal?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/04/18/c-runtime-deployment-why-choosing-applocal/)). Although not initially planned, this was later enabled and communicated on September 11, 2015 (see [Introducing the Universal CRT](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/03/03/introducing-the-universal-crt/)).

Comment: To recap:
1. Starting from VC++ 2015, C++ app requires Universal CRT.
2. A serious bug in the Universal CRT was discovered that breaks all MFC apps due to MFC’s use of _sntscanf_s in its DDX_Text routine for doubles.  This bug is in ucrtbase.dll
3. Universal CRT can only be reliably updated by Windows update for Windows Vista, 7, 8, 8.1 and 10.  VC++ redistributable package (or even VS 2017 itself) is not reliable in updating Universal CRT.
4. Yes, I am to use app-local deployment.  It is not an optimal solution but probably a good solution considering the mess that Microsoft had created.

Comment: does anyone know if this issue was fixed by Microsoft or not in later VC++ versions?

Comment: @user1998863 yes , this has been fixed long ago.